# Electronic program guide (EPG) XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

Is there a way to implement [EPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_program_guide) using XAML for WinPhone/WinRT? I saw a lot of iOS/Android/Web apps doing this, but not WP or WinStore.

1. It should support large number of items (500 channels, N programs for each, where N is number of programs during week)
2. It can have gaps inside, like some program is missing or no data from whole row, but empty (transparent) row still should be displayed.
3. Number of items in each row will be always different (thats how EPG works)
4. Loading should be fast and scrolling smooth.
5. Memory usage should be normal , app should not crash becasue of many drawn views ie elements need to be virtualized(reused)

GridView looks like something similar, but there are some issues:

- to make items different size of items - need to switch itemsPanel to VariableSizedWrapGrid, which not supports virtualization. There are some attempts to solve this issue, like [this](https://windevgo.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/virtualize-the-variablesizedwrapgrid/) but not native/tested/wide-used solution
- not sure that even with VariableSizedWrapGrid it will be possible to support gaps and absence of content, looks like GridView will fill elements in gaps in any case (creating empty transparent items sounds like dirty hack)
- many items will be the problem, need to somehow do incremental loading
- memory usage / performance desnt looks good

Did someone implement this? Is there any component/guide for this? Which xaml control will allow this and how about performance/memory/time to appear?

Comment: have you got it working ?

Answer (score 0):

I've did a xaml epg for `UWP` not a while ago, after lots of POCs I've used a simple Grid with `ScrollViewer` which columns and rows are generated dynamically from the code behind (most of the code was on code behind) and a couple of `ListView` .

We've also wrote our own data virtualization (since Grid doesn't supports virtualization)...

WinRT XAML Toolkit - was very handy

It wasn't a simple task but it's duable :)

Assuming that you have some model of the EPG data, something like - 
List (each channel has a List of Programs)

**What I did, is** - 
I created an empty Grid wrapped inside of ScrollViewer, and then I've associated a RowDefinition for each channel, and then added is to the grid (by channel index).

**Spreading the programs** - was more complex (because some of programs has time overlapping). I added each program as Border element to the channels RowDefinitios  - placing it by **Margin to Time** calculation.

**Data Virtualization** - What I did is calculating the period of time that is visible to user (a  ViewPort of type Rect) then, when user scrolled - I've loaded only the programs/channels that are intersects with the viewPort. For instance if the user is viewing EPg from 14:00-18:00 I wouldn't load 18:05 program to the view.

**Selecting a program (expanding for details)**-  you can simply set width of the selected Program and its RowDefinition when you select.

- The main issue here is the keyboard novigation (which is really tough thing to implement) but if you touch/mouse oriented then your navigation problem solved.

Comment: I can't but I'll try to explain the main idea